# Правка адреса на сайте

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Тема из ряда "кто как делает".

```
//URL на сайте типа:
mysite.ru/catalog/category-name/page-3/?get1=***&get2=***

Содержимое адреса я не знаю, по этому, для замены на page-4 делаю:
$url_ex1    = explode('page-',$url);      //отрезаем все, что перед номером страницы
$url_ex2    = explode('/',$url_ex1[1]);   //отрезаем все, что после номера страницы
$url_ex2[0] = 4;                          //новый номер страницы
$url_ex1[1] = implode('/',$url_ex2);      //соединяем конец адреса
$url        = implode('page-',$url_ex1);  //соединяем начало адреса
```

Собственно кто и что может сказать о конструкции? Может кто знает способ легче? Потенциально адрес мне не известен, так что хотелось бы узнать решение для конкретно этого варианта и вообще.

p.s. мечтаю в php6 о таком:

```
$url = ichem_ot_i_do_i_zamenyaem($url,'page-','/','4'); //**kcyeah!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
$page = 4 ; 
$newurl = preg_replace('/page-\d{1,}/','page-'.$page, $url);
```

Comment: Блин, оно самое! Пойду разберусь с preg_replace